# How to resolve "InaccessibleObjectException" of jdk16

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm, cglib

I met a problem when I work for the framework: https://github.com/babyfish-ct/kimmer/

After I published the first version. I run the example, an exception raised

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(byte[],int,int) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @74ea2410
```

This framework uses [ASM](https://asm.ow2.io/) to generate bytecode directly. It doesn't matter, using the higher-level [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) framework will encounter the same problem.

The problem is my framework(or cglib) wants to define new classes by runtime generated bytecode on **EXISTING** ClassLoader. To do this, I need to access protection-level methods under java.lang.ClassLoader through reflection, get the **PROTECTED** method and change its visibility, like this

```
private val DEFINE_CLASS = ClassLoader::class.java.getDeclaredMethod(
    "defineClass",
    ByteArray::class.java,
    Int::class.javaPrimitiveType,
    Int::class.javaPrimitiveType,
).also {
    it.isAccessible = true
}
```

Actually, I learned this trick from cglib's source code 10 years ago，this trick has been helping me.

Now, The JDK has become strict and this behavior is prohibited. I had to go and read the source code of the latest version of cglib. In [ReflectUtils.java](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/blob/975e481faf39c91b8ac5b9b3d62822b7c52c5f47/cglib/src/main/java/net/sf/cglib/core/ReflectUtils.java), I found cglib is trying to use "defineClass" of "sun.misc.Unsafe". Unfortunately, I can find that class but cannot find that method in "OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu16.30+19-CA".

I feel this problem is caused by jigsaw but I'm not jigsaw expert, so I left it open and let the user use "--illegal-access=permit".

How to resolve this problem and let my problems can work perfectly on latest JVM?

Comment: The official replacement for "define class in an existing ClassLoader" is [`MethodHandles.lookup().defineClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/invoke/MethodHandles.Lookup.html#defineClass%28byte%5B%5D%29)

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

BTW, after test. This problem can be resolved by https://github.com/jboss-javassist/javassist/blob/master/src/main/javassist/util/proxy/DefineClassHelper.java perfectly, I will use some of its code to fix this problem

Comment: Hi Johannes

Finally I used this solution, 0.0.1 is published, prefect, thanks

Comment: The method `sun.misc.Unsafe.defineClass` has been removed. Likewise, the option `--illegal-access` has no effect on recent JDKs anymore. That linked helper class is annoyingly complicated; Johannes Kuhn’s solution exists since JDK 9 and in versions before that, the deep Reflection on `ClassLoader.defineClass` still works. So why bother with more than these two approaches?